# Combining Firebase Queries with GeoQuery to search Posts by name in nearby area

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm making an android app where user can find a book in his/her vicinity and buy it if interested. I am using firebase and geoqueries/geofire. 
I want to make a SearchActivity where user can search a book by it's title in his/her vicinity.

my Firebase Database Structure looks like :

```
books
   PushKey
      g:
      l:
         0:
         1:
      name:"some book name"
```

If i try to query this with some book name, it works fine using :

```
myRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("some book name").addChildEventListener()....//The rest of the code here...
```

If i try to query nearby books,then also it works fine using :

```
geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(myLocation, 10);
```

I'm stuck at combining these two.
How can i search for a specific book name only in the vicinity?
For example : I want to search a book whose name is "ABCD" and is in a radius of 10km.
OR
Search a book by name and tell which one is nearest(In case several books are uploaded with same name at different locations).
Is it possible to do so? If not, what workaround(maybe other than firebase, but has to cheap and affordable) can i opt for where i can achieve this desired result?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database can only query by a single property. The fact that GeoFire does something that is seemingly at odds with that (querying by longitude and latitude) is because it combines these values into a single property in a magical format called a geohash (the `g` property in your JSON).

Combining values into a single property is the only way to get Firebase to filter on multiple values. For example, you could prefix the `g` property with your book title to get `some book name_geohashvalue` and could then filter on that.

The two main problems with that:

1. This only works if you know the entire book title, you can do a prefix match on the title, as you'll already need to use the prefix match for the geohash.
2. This is not built in to GeoFire, so you will have to fork that library and build it yourself.

If you do try to do this yourself, and get stuck, we can try to help. But fair warning: this won't be trivial, and you'll need to understand how geohashes, geofire, and Firebase's query model work quite well. For an intro, I recommend watching the video of my talk on [performing geoqueries on Firebase and Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).

If you want something a bit less involved, you have two main options:

1. Retrieve all nodes within range, and then filter for the book title client-side.
2. Store a separate GeoFire tree for each book title, so that you can initialize your GeoFire object based on the book title, and only get keys within range for that specific book title.

Between these two, I'd recommend starting with #1.